# $a^m+b^n = c^k$ and the $abc$ conjecture

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

(Inspired by the Reddit post [here](https://old.reddit.com/r/math/comments/17die53/are_there_any_integers_a_b_c_for_which_a2_b2_c3/))

Let $m, n, k$ be integers with $m, n>2$ and $k\ge 2$. I'm wondering what we can say about solutions of the Diophantine equation $a^m+b^n = c^k$. Of course, when $\gcd(m, n, k)>2$ this has no solutions by Fermat's Last Theorem.

Assuming $abc$ conjecture, we know for any $\epsilon$ that $c^2<_\epsilon \mathrm{rad}(abc)^{1+\epsilon}$ for all but finitely many coprime $(a, b, c)$. It seems to me that we can choose some $\epsilon$ so that the RHS is $<c^2$ and hence for all but finitely many coprime $(a, b, c)$, though I'm not sure how to get there. Is my intuition correct? If so, how can we approach this (and is there a simpler approach)?

Comment: This is the subject of the Beal conjecture, which is wide open, but you can check Wikipedia for a list of partial results: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beal_conjecture

Comment: Thank you. I see that $abc$ conjecture does imply what I want (that there are finitely many counterexamples).